# Read flat file to DataFrames using Pandas with field specifiers in-line

Tags: python, pandas

I'm attempting to read in a flat-file to a DataFrame using pandas but can't seem to get the format right.  My file has a variable number of fields represented per line and looks like this:

```
TIME=20131203004552049|CHAN=FCJNJKDCAAANPCKEAAAAAAAA|EVNT=NVOCinpt|MIME=application/synthesis+ssml|TXID=NUAN-20131203004552049-FCJNJKDCAAANPCKEAAAAAAAA-txt|TXSZ=1167|UCPU=31|SCPU=15
TIME=20131203004552049|CHAN=FCJNJKDCAAANPCKEAAAAAAAA|EVNT=NVOCsynd|INPT=1167|DURS=5120|RSTT=stop|UCPU=31|SCPU=15
TIME=20131203004552049|CHAN=FCJNJKDCAAANPCKEAAAAAAAA|EVNT=NVOClise|LUSED=0|LMAX=100|OMAX=95|LFEAT=tts|UCPU=0|SCPU=0
```

I have the field separator at `|`, I've pulled a list of all unique keys into `keylist`, and am trying to use the following to read in the data:

```
keylist = ['TIME',
             'CHAN',
             # [truncated]
             'DURS',
             'RSTT']

test_fp = 'c:\\temp\\test_output.txt'
df = pd.read_csv(test_fp, sep='|', names=keylist)
```

This incorrectly builds the DataFrame as I'm not specifying any way to recognize the key label in the line.  I'm a little stuck and am not sure which way to research -- should I be using `.read_json()` for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if there's a slick way to do this.  Sometimes when the data structure is different enough from the norm it's easiest to preprocess it on the Python side.  Sure, it's not as fast, but since you could immediately save it in a more standard format it's usually not worth worrying about.

One way:

```
with open("wfield.txt") as fp:
    rows = (dict(entry.split("=",1) for entry in row.strip().split("|")) for row in fp)
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(rows)
```

which produces

```
>>> df
                       CHAN  DURS      EVNT  INPT LFEAT LMAX LUSED  \
0  FCJNJKDCAAANPCKEAAAAAAAA   NaN  NVOCinpt   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   
1  FCJNJKDCAAANPCKEAAAAAAAA  5120  NVOCsynd  1167   NaN  NaN   NaN   
2  FCJNJKDCAAANPCKEAAAAAAAA   NaN  NVOClise   NaN   tts  100     0   

                         MIME OMAX  RSTT SCPU               TIME  \
0  application/synthesis+ssml  NaN   NaN   15  20131203004552049   
1                         NaN  NaN  stop   15  20131203004552049   
2                         NaN   95   NaN    0  20131203004552049   

                                                TXID  TXSZ UCPU  
0  NUAN-20131203004552049-FCJNJKDCAAANPCKEAAAAAAA...  1167   31  
1                                                NaN   NaN   31  
2                                                NaN   NaN    0  

[3 rows x 15 columns]
```

After you've got this, you can reshape as needed.  (I'm not sure if you wanted to combine rows with the same TIME & CHAN or not.)

---

Edit: if you're using an older version of pandas which doesn't support passing a generator to `from_dict`, you can built it from a list instead:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(rows))
```

but note that you haev have to convert columns to numerical columns from strings after the fact.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how to write this legibly, but I get a pandas error: `PandasError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!`.  I'm using Python 2.7.5 from Anaconda 1.8.0.  Testing by setting the 3 lines of sample text as `str = '''<3 lines of sample flat file>'''` then changing your `with` line to `for fp in str.split('\n'):` if that makes sense.  (link to my [test code](http://pastebin.com/JAGSpcQp))

Comment: @tommy_o: your `for fp in str:` loop is doing the same thing as my `for row in fp`, so the loops don't make sense now, which is the first issue.  Do you see the problem?

Comment: oh gosh sorry.  the code you have there (when using my flat file of 1000 lines) doesnt work me, then I broke it further.  this pastebin has the contents of `test_output.txt` and the code (including `PandasError`) from IPython: http://pastebin.com/sHfuMRDC .  If using that, does it work for you?

Comment: Yep, works perfectly. What version of `pandas` are you using? (I'm using 0.13.)  .. ah, that's it.  I just tried it in a version of 0.11 and got your error message.  Let me see how to do it in that version.

Comment: Looks like Anaconda 1.8.0  ships with pandas 0.12.0